# Tkinter Toplevel window formatted Table

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this method below:

```
def viewTable(self):
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('Table')
    Label (toplevel, text='Course').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)
```

I also have a dictionary with `{course: "hoursUsed hoursAllowed Comment"}` and I want to print this dictionary in a formatted table in the toplevel window, like with column headers and proper spacing. How do I go about this? Thanks.

Gave this more thought and I am looking into grid instead of pack.

For those wondering: I switched all my .pack() to .grid(). It was a lot of work, but I really needed the formatting and grid works so well for that.

Comment: Perhaps something like tktable would be of help?

Comment: @apgwoz I didn't find that method in my searches. Printing with a grid helped though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have sent along a link: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTable

Comment: @apgwoz I actually have to improve what I wrote during this week and I may try to implement this table instead of doing a printed format. Thanks!